IIS Connection Count - How to get all the source ip addresses connected to the server at a certain point in time
I have an asp.net app (.Net 4.6 mvc) hosted on a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter IIS.
I've set some monitors that fire when the connection count is >= 400
Is it possible to check ip addresses for all these 400 connections and the Url that was requested?
Thank

There isn't a builtin mechanism to give you real time insights on those (third party products can, which you might learn from search engines). IIS log files (once written out) can help you analyze them afterwards.
